# What is the best way to move updated files from Mac/windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm very new to coding and building my first rails website.

I use a Mac laptop to edit when I'm not home and a windows desktop. Up until now I've been using Dropbox to store the files and uploading/downloading from there when required.

The last time I tried uploading from my Mac, it didn't copy many files at all and I was wondering what the best way to do this going forward would be?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a proper version control system, such as git or mercurial. So you'd upload your code to a central repository (github, for example) from your mac and get/fetch these latest updates on windows. And vice versa.

This might seem like an overly complicated solution to this problem, but you'll have to learn version control anyway. Might as well start now.